# create exact number of pulses in raspberry pi with DMA library to control industrial Delta Servo Motor angel and rotation

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi-2, pigpio

i want to control exactly how mush my servo rotate through DMA like pigpio with raspberry pi so i need to create exact number of pulses for servo . 
is there anyway to create exact number of pulses with DMA like pigpio or servoblaser ?
by the way i am using a Delta Servo motor with its driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pigpio [wave chains](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_chain) to send pulses a precise number of times.

However this is of no use for servos (unless yours has a special interface).

Hobby servos work in one of two ways.

1. pulses are sent at 50Hz.  The length of each pulse in microseconds
   (generally in the range 1000-2000) determine the servo horns target angle.
2. pulses are sent at 50Hz.  The length of each pulse in microseconds
   (generally in the range 1000-2000) determine the servo horns rotational speed.

The number of pulses sent in total is not relevant.

---

The following script shows how to use wave chains with Python.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio

def tx_pulses(pi, GPIO, hertz, num, pulse_len=1):
   assert hertz < 500000
   length_us = int(1000000/hertz)
   assert int(pulse_len) < length_us
   assert num < 65536

   num_low = num % 256
   num_high = num // 256

   wf = []

   wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0, pulse_len))
   wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<GPIO, length_us - pulse_len))

   pi.wave_add_generic(wf)

   wid = pi.wave_create()

   if wid >= 0:
      pi.wave_chain([255, 0, wid, 255, 1, num_low, num_high])
      while pi.wave_tx_busy():
         time.sleep(0.01)
      pi.wave_delete(wid)

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit()

GPIO=19

pi.set_mode(GPIO, pigpio.OUTPUT)

tx_pulses(pi, GPIO, 100, 25) # 25 pulses @ 100 Hz

tx_pulses(pi, GPIO, 1000, 250) # 250 pulses @ 1000 Hz

tx_pulses(pi, GPIO, 5000, 2391, pulse_len=50) # 2391 pulses @ 5000 Hz

pi.stop()
```

Comment: thanks but i am using Delta Servo Motor an industrial servo . not Hobby servos .. for example i used your HP command line pigs commands throw terminal, and i see when i increase frequency i get more speed .. so it means more pulses : more speed . these servos have an driver .. and driver  determine how much for a pulse servo rotate.

Comment: and by the way is there any example of using your wave chains function ? i couldn't understand how actually create one ...

Comment: Each of the C, pdif2, and Python documentation for the wave chain call contain an example.  There may be other examples in http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html but I'm not sure.

Comment: I would look into the driver and see what it expects, usually they are driven with PWM (as explained in the answer), not number of pulses.  Now if it is a stepper motor that moves a small fraction of a rotation with every pulse then more pulses would = more rotation/speed

Comment: thanks Johan and Chad, (http://www.deltaww.com/Products/CategoryListT1.aspx?CID=060201&PID=1149&hl=en-US&Name=ASDA-A2R%20Series ) this is link to know better what driver i am using. it actually respond to rising edge of electrical pulse . so i need exact number of pulse . in the driver we set driver setting . for example if i set in driver when 100 rising edge occurred then servo rotate 1 degree.. so i need exact number of pulses. if i have more frequency then servo rotates more quickly.

Comment: @joan thanks again . something i did't understand is what is the procedure of creating wave chains . first we to create one by some unctions and then transmit it ... and i can not find any documentation about pigpio.pulse function that you use in example of wave chain in in page ?

Comment: @pooya What language would you prefer to use?  Which (Broadcom) GPIO, how many pulses, and over what time period?

Comment: for example in gpio 19, 25 pulses and over 150 microsecond create one pulse (one rising edge) in python for example .. or pigs terminal

Comment: Try `sudo pigpiod`, then `GPIO19=$((1<<19)); pigs m 19 w; pigs wvag $GPIO19 0 1 0 $GPIO19 1; pigs wvcre; pigs wvcha 255 0 0 255 2 4 0 255 1 25 0`.  This creates wave (#0) as a microsecond on and off for GPIO19.  This is transmitted with the wave chain command looping 25 times with a delay of 4 micros after the 2 microsecond wave.

Comment: oh i think i need python  code ... Sorry . because i use your piscope and didn't get any pulse on gpio19

Comment: @joan. in your comment you mention this : GPIO19=$((1<<19)) . how can i use hex address of GPIO19. i am sending these code from java to execute in terminal  , GPIO19=$((1<<19)) doesn't work , so i need hex address pi pin

Comment: For the wave generic command you set bit X if you want GPIO X to be selected.  1<<X is just an easy way to select bit X from the command line. Just bit 19 set is decimal 524288, or hex 0x80000.

Comment: You should edit your question to include links/details of the servo you are using.  The question makes better sense if you know the servo is industrial.  This sort of detail in comments will be missed by most who come across the question.